# make check failed for GMP when building GCC 5.3

Tags: gcc, gmp

I am trying to build GCC 5.3 from source with gmp, mpfr, mpc, isl downloaded using contrib/download_prerequisites. `make -j4` finished with no errors. However, when I run `make check`, I got the following message:

```
make[6]: Entering directory `/iac/source/gcc-5.3.0_bk/host-x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu/gmp/tests/mpz'
...
PASS: t-lucnum_ui
/bin/sh: line 4: 31398 Segmentation fault      (core dumped) ${dir}$tst
FAIL: t-scan
...
====================================
1 of 58 tests failed
Please report to gmp-bugs at gmplib.org
====================================
make[4]: *** [check-TESTS] Error 1
make[4]: Leaving directory `/opt/downloads/gmp-4.3.2/tests/mpz'
make[3]: *** [check-am] Error 2
make[3]: Leaving directory `/opt/downloads/gmp-4.3.2/tests/mpz'
make[2]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory `/opt/downloads/gmp-4.3.2/tests'
make[1]: *** [check-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/opt/downloads/gmp-4.3.2'
make: *** [check] Error 2
```

I see someone's archive here with the full output:

https://gmplib.org/list-archives/gmp-bugs/2013-July/003109.html

Seems this is an GMP issue. Is this critical? how can I fix it?

Can anyone help me? thank you in advance.

Comment: It's almost certainly not critical, so you can probably ignore it. If you are concerned you could download a newer version of GMP and put that in the GCC source tree instead of the old version fetched by `contrib/download_prerequisites`. What version of GCC was used to build 5.3?

Comment: The issue is that download_prerequisites downloads a prehistorical version of GMP. (IIRC the issue is in the test, not in the library)